# Checking a map statically at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, std

So, I'll preface this question with that I am not sure if this is even possible.

Anyways, I am attempting to have a static const map (or something similar) checked at compile time to verify it will have a matching value (an id in this case). Specifically, I currently have something bad like this (but it doesn't compile):

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeMapChecker
{
    static const std::map<std::type_info, MessageID> type_map;
    static const bool contains = (type_map.count(typeid(T)) > 0);
}

template<typename T> 
const std::map<std::type_info, MessageID> TypeMapChecker<T>::type_map = {
    { typeid(ClassA), MESSAGE_A_ID }, 
    { typeid(ClassB), MESSAGE_B_ID }
};

..........

template<typename T0, typename T1>
class MessagePair
{
    static const bool t0Has = TypeMapChecker<T0>::contains;
    static const bool t1Has = TypeMapChecker<T1>::contains;
    static_assert (t0Has && t1Has, "I'M ASSERTING MY AUTHORITY, YOU MALIGNANT CODERS");
}
```

Something like that. This doesn't build because "expected a constant expression" at:

```
static const bool contains = (type_map.count(typeid(T)) > 0);
```

Just want to validate that when I access the type_map in MessagePair I am guaranteed a value at build time, and don't have to rely on runtime shenanigans since this is a large code base modified by many (and I can't stop them from doing bad things at runtime). Other implementations or any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that with maps, but if you want a compile time type container and query for membership, you can use a type list. http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00681.html

Comment: @imreal So that list is just a look up of whether the type is in the list right? Just at a glance, I don't think I'd be able to tack on a return id without becoming a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: correct, however you could use a type traits to get the id of a type.

Comment: @imreal Funny you should say that, because the main reasoning behind trying to implement this "hacky" code is because someone decided to use typeid hash code in file operations. Typeid hash code is not guaranteed to be the same between platforms, it's not even guaranteed between runs. I'm attempting to replace the hash codes with statically defined ids, but I haven't found a good way to ensure an ID is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the map as a type.

Use the type to build your runtime typeid map.

Here is the key-value pair for your compile-time map:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
struct entry {
  using key=Key;
  using value=Value;
};
```

We then make a map from it:

```
template<class T> struct tag_t{using type=T; constexpr tag_t(){};};
template<class T> constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

template<class...Entries>
struct compile_time_map:Entries... {
  template<class Key>
  struct lookup {
    template<class Value>
    constexpr tag_t<Value> operator()( entry<Key, Value> const& ) const { return {}; }
  };
  template<class Key>
  constexpr
  std::result_of_t< lookup<Key>( compile_time_map ) > operator()( tag_t<Key> ) const {
    return {};
  }
  template<class...Key>
  constexpr std::false_type operator()( tag_t<Key...> ) const {
    return {};
  }
  template<class MessageID>
  std::map< std::type_index, MessageID > make_map() const {
    return { {typeid(typename Entries::key), typename Entries::value{}}... };
  }

  template<class Key>
  constexpr auto has(tag_t<Key> ={}) const {
    return std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_same< std::result_of_t< compile_time_map(tag_t<Key>)>, std::false_type >{}>{};
  }
};
```

This map can generate a run-time map of a type of your choice.

```
using ID=unsigned;

template<class T, ID id>
using make_entry = entry<T, std::integral_constant<ID, id>>;

using ctm = compile_time_map<
  make_entry< int, 7 >,
  make_entry< double, 3 >,
  make_entry< std::string, (unsigned)-1 >
>;

auto rtm = ctm{}.make_map<ID>();
```

we can do compile-time lookups with `ctm{}( tag<int> )`.  We can do runtime lookups with `rtm[ typeid(int) ]`.

We can check if there is an entry at compile time with `ctm{}.has<int>()` or `ctm{}.has( tag<int> )`.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99ccb93ec853cc54).